# XQuery grouping and finding max values

Tags: xml, group-by, xquery, grouping

my XML document looks like the following:

```
<books>
    <book><author>A</author></book>
    <book><author>B</author></book>
    <book><author>C</author></book>
    <book><author>B</author></book>
    <book><author>C</author></book>
</books>
```

Now, the query should return the name of the authors with the most books. In this case `B,C` (since both have 2 books). The problem is, that it has to be only one query, so finding the maximum (2) and then searching for authors with 2 books is not an acceptable solution in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by the authors and store the immediate result together with the count of their publications. Then filter to return only the authors with maximal publication count.

```
let $authors :=
  for $book in //book
  let $author := $book/author
  group by $author
  return <author count="{ count($book) }">{ $author }</author>
return $authors[@count = max($authors/@count)]/data()
```

Comment: This is exactly what OP said he didn't want, since it does 2 passes, although I think that's simply not possible.

Comment: This is a single query. Without storing an intermediate result it isn't possible, because you've got to find out what's the maximum before filtering. An alternative would be sorting `$authors` and comparing with the first result, but probably has better optimization potential, but in the ends also breaks the execution pipeline.

Comment: I agree with you, but calling this a single query is a stretch. I think in the original question OP said that he didn't want 2-pass. If you want that kind of query it requires an index with frequency data.

Comment: What the OP said was "it has to be only one query", not "I don't want a two-pass solution".  Where I come from, a "query" in XQuery is a syntactic construct (specifically, what the spec calls a query module and what engines handle with a single call), not an ill-defined notion of 'looking at things a single time'.  There's no reasonable way to describe Jens Erat's suggestion as anything but a single query.